# Move an element to the right side then return to left side

Tags: javascript, html

In short, I want to move an element to the right side, and when arrives to the right, coming back again to the left, and so on `("ex: hit a ball to a wall, then it come back to you again")`.

But there is an error in moving the element !.

> The Code

```js
var Ball = document.getElementById('ball');
var ballPosition = 0;

var pageWidth = document.body.offsetWidth;

var Loop = setInterval(function () {
    ballPosition = Ball.offsetLeft;

    if (ballPosition < pageWidth) {
        Ball.style.left = ballPosition + 10 + "px";
    } else {
        Ball.style.left = ballPosition - 10 + "px";
    }
}, 1000 / 60);
```

```html
<div id="ball" style="width:70px; height:70px; margin:0; padding:0; border-radius:50px; position:absolute; background-color:#ff0000"> </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try having a `ballSpeed` variable, and multiply it by `-1` when it reaches the left or the right side:

```js
var ball = document.getElementById('ball'),
  ballPosition = 0,
  ballSpeed = 10,
  pageWidth = document.body.offsetWidth - ball.offsetWidth;
setInterval(function() {
  ball.style.left = (ballPosition += ballSpeed) + 'px';
  if (ballPosition <= 0 || ballPosition >= pageWidth) {
    ballSpeed *= -1;
  }
}, 1000 / 60);
```

```css
#ball {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div id="ball"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need JavaScript, you could use a CSS3 animation:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8qjph5bg/)

```css
.ball {
    width: 70px; height: 70px;
    border-radius: 50%; position:absolute;
    background-color: #f00;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-animation: move 2s infinite linear forwards;
    animation: move 2s infinite linear forwards;
}
@keyframes move {
    50% { left: calc(100% - 70px); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
    50% { left: calc(100% - 70px); }
}
```

```html
<div class="ball"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is just the beginning to complete the work by using javascript.

Comment: @LionKing I was just going by the example you posted, and you did tag [CSS] in the question.

Comment: I'm so sorry about added css tag, and thank you again for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a direction variable to determine if the ball should be moving left or right and change the direction whenever the ball hits the edges.

```js
var Ball = document.getElementById('ball');
var ballPosition = 0;
var direction = 1;

var pageWidth = document.body.offsetWidth;

var Loop = setInterval(function () {
    ballPosition = Ball.offsetLeft;

    if (ballPosition > pageWidth) {
        direction = -1;
    } else if (ballPosition < 0){
        direction = 1;
    }
    Ball.style.left = (ballPosition + direction*10) + "px";

}, 1000 / 60);
```

```html
<div id="ball" style="width:70px; height:70px; margin:0; padding:0; border-radius:50px; position:absolute; background-color:#ff0000"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When your ball hit to a wall (`else`-part), it trying to go back, but it's position less then page width and.. it hit to a wall again.

Just add any flag (bool) for your ball. When it hit a wall you should set `flag = true` and then check this flag in your condition.

```js
var Ball = document.getElementById('ball');
var ballPosition = 0;

var pageWidth = document.body.offsetWidth;
var hitted = false;

var Loop = setInterval(function () {
ballPosition = Ball.offsetLeft;

if (!hitted) {
    Ball.style.left = ballPosition + 10 + "px";
    hitted = (ballPosition > pageWidth);
} else {
    Ball.style.left = ballPosition - 10 + "px";
    hitted = !(ballPosition < 0);
}
  
}, 1000 / 60);
```

```html
<div id="ball" style="width:70px; height:70px; margin:0; padding:0; border-radius:50px; position:absolute; background-color:#ff0000"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what you need to change your code, so it start all over when it gets to end of the page, hope this helps

```js
var Ball = document.getElementById('ball');
var ballPosition = 0;

var pageWidth = document.body.offsetWidth;

var Loop = setInterval(function () {
    ballPosition = Ball.offsetLeft;

    if (ballPosition < pageWidth) {
        Ball.style.left = ballPosition + 10 + "px";
    } else {
        Ball.style.left = 0 + "px";
    }
}, 1000 / 60);
```

```html
<div id="ball" style="width:70px; height:70px; margin:0; padding:0; border-radius:50px; position:absolute; background-color:#ff0000"> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the ball doesn't come back again, this is just restart the movement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use translate if the `calc` function is not wanted see @Josh Crozier

```css
.ball {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-animation: zigzag 3s infinite ease;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zigzag {
  50% {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
    margin-left: -64px
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="ball"></div>
```